# FLTK color if statement

Tags: if-statement, colors, fltk

is there a way to write an if statement in an fltk project such that it looks at the colour of an Fl_Box, and then returns a value? 
Something like this:
if(color(Fl_Box)==FL_Blue)
{int i=0}
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, all widgets have the `color()` function (see http://www.fltk.org/doc-1.3/classFl__Widget.html#a03c07e0725994cddf9070f9f1cd215c4 ).

If you look in `Enumerations.H` in the FLTK includes folder is has `const Fl_Color FL_BLUE    = 216;` so you would want to use `FL_BLUE` and naturally you would need to actually have a pointer to the widget in question so you would have

```
  if (some_box->color()==FL_BLUE)
```

where somewhere else in your code you have

```
  Fl_Box* some_box;
  some_box = new Fl_Box(x,y,w,h,"Name");
```